# python list to 'n' number of strings depending on length of list

Tags: python, list, loops

Consider the below `list` in Python.

```
c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
```

I want to create `n` strings where `n = len(c)/6`. So for this example, the expected output would be:

```
str1=1|2|3|4|5|6
str2=7|8|9|10|11|12
str3=13|14|15|16|17|18
```

How do I do it using loops? Note that the length of `c` will always be a multiple of `6`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `comprehension` to generate the `sub-list` chunks, and then unpack into variables:

```
c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
str1, str2, str3 = (c[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(c), 6))
```

Or, if you actually want `strings` like: `'1|2|3|4|5|6'` then you can use `str.join` on the `sub-lists` but this will require converting everything to `strings` first:

```
str1, str2, str3 = ('|'.join(map(str, c[i:i+6])) for i in range(0, len(c), 6))
```

which gives:

```
>>> str1
'1|2|3|4|5|6'
>>> str2
'7|8|9|10|11|12'
>>> str3
'13|14|15|16|17|18'
```

*Note that in the second snippet, you could use a `generator-expression` instead of `map()` which is usually considered more Pythonic, but they take up more characters for simple things (like converting to `strings`).*

Comment: Oops didn't see your answer. I'll delete mine.

Comment: @RoadRunner No problem! Happens to me all the time, turns out I actually wrote another part to mine (the string mapping bit) whilst you were writing yours :)

Comment: yeah, happens all too often. Your answer is 10 x better anyways because it explains the process. I'll give the upvote to you and delete mine :).

Comment: @RoadRunner Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
>>> str1, str2, str3 = map('|'.join, zip(*[map(str, c)]*6))
>>> str1, str2, str3
('1|2|3|4|5|6', '7|8|9|10|11|12', '13|14|15|16|17|18')
```

On Python 2 use `from itertools import imap`

---

If you use [`more_itertools`](http://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library you can look even nicer:

```
>>> from more_itertools import grouper
>>> c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
>>> str1, str2, str3 = map('|'.join, grouper(6, map(str, c)))
>>> str1, str2, str3
('1|2|3|4|5|6', '7|8|9|10|11|12', '13|14|15|16|17|18')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion :

```
c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]

multiple=len(c)/6

def hello(c1,g1):

    if not c1:
        return 0
    else:
        print(c1[:g1])
        return hello(c1[g1:],g1)
print(hello(c,int(len(c)/multiple)))
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use join here:

```
c=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]

n = len(c)/3
for i in range(0,len(c),n):
    print "|".join(str(x) for x in c[i:i+n])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for` loop would be something like:

```
strings = []
sl_sz = 6
for i in range(0, len(c) / sl_sz):
    strings.append("|".join(map(str, c[i*sl_sz:(i + 1)*sl_sz])))
```

Comment: You can set the `step` value of range to `6`, and then the code will become much neater. Also, your `lambda` function is unnecessary, it *literally* carries out `str()` so just do: `map(str, ...)`!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is by using `islice` from `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import islice

c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]

str1, str2, str3 = ["|".join(map(str, list(islice(c,i*6,i*6+6)))) for i in range(len(c)//6)]

print(str1)
print(str2)
print(str3)
```

Output:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6
7|8|9|10|11|12
13|14|15|16|17|18
```